# Работа с Apple Script

Tags: macos, mac, apple

Кто знает, как на apple script работать с браузером? Как обработать такое всплывающее окно [image]

Как программно ввести логин/пароль?

Comment: Примочки типа 1Password или LastPass — не вариант?

Comment: нет, мне это не нужно - для просто хранения паролей хватает keychain.
Вообще мне уже это не нужно, а нужно как то нажать кнопку на html странице?